# android.util.Config.DEBUG always false even when developing and debugging in eclipse. Why?

Tags: android, logging

When developing in eclipse, the android.util.Config.DEBUG constant is always false even when I debug the project.

The javadoc for this constant says that "If this is a debug build, this field will be true." What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "build" mentioned in the document is not your application build, but the Android system build.

The value of Config.DEBUG **ONLY** depends on the system (ROM) of your device, nothing to do with your application. On a device with production build ROM, Config.DEBUG is alway false no matter how you set USB debugging on device and debuggable flag in manifest.

If the document is written like: "If the Android system is a debug build, this field will be true.", then it will be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/be329298953aa8bd

I think given the above link that the answer lies with the device and not only your app.

Have you gone into your devices settings and turned on debugging?

Go to Settings>Application settings>Development and ensure USB debugging is on.

[Edit]
And ensure that in your manifest file you've put debuggable="true"

```
<manifest>
...
<application android:debuggable="true" >
```

Comment: In the development window of the preferences, USB deubugging (debug mode when USB is connected) is on.